# Can't Add Podcast Episodes to Ipod After Upgrading to 12.04

Tags: upgrade, rhythmbox, ipod

Since upgrading to 12.04, dragging podcast episodes doesn't move them onto my ipod.

Adding songs from the library works fine, but if I do it with a podcast nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the exact issue was, but I was able to solve it by deleting `~/.gconf/apps/rhythmbox/%gconf.xml`.

After that, Rhythmbox transfer worked fine once I restarted the program.

Thanks to [this article](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-fix-rhythmbox-iphoneipod-sync-issues.html), which contained the solution.