# Ipod Suddenly Stopped Working With Ubuntu

Tags: rhythmbox, ipod

Until recently, my ipod has connected to Ubuntu with no problems, but a couple days ago it is no longer able to do so.

The ipod mounts when connected, but it mounts to a random folder in /tmp and is not recognized by any programs.

If I manually unmount it and mount it in /media, it's recognized. However, trying to do anything with it crashes whatever program I'm trying to use (in particular, Rhythmbox, which has been my preferred program to use with the ipod so far).

However, if I go into the device, the files can be played (with, say, VLC) fine. It's only causing issues when using programs that treat it as a music player.

Floola says that the ipod is write-only, but I set the fstab entry to rw and umask=000.

Earlier, after upgrading to 12.04, I had some issues with loading podcasts onto the ipod, prompting [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186042/cant-add-podcast-episodes-to-ipod-after-upgrading-to-12-04) question here.  This problem started a couple days after that one was solved. I have no idea if they are related, but it seemed worth considering.

Other than that, I can't recall changing anything, except perhaps to install Ubuntu updates once or twice.